# how to remove a few lines of tags and it's content from xml with regex

Tags: php, regex, xml

how can I remove a few lines of tags and it's content from xml with regex and php?

i've tried with:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<\JournalIssue CitedMedium="Print">.*?<\/JournalIssue>/i', '', $content);
```

xml to remove:

```
<JournalIssue CitedMedium="Print">
<Volume>38</Volume>
<Issue>1-2</Issue>
<PubDate>
<MedlineDate>2017 Jan-Jun</MedlineDate>
</PubDate>
</JournalIssue>
```

Answer (score 1):

While possible for specific cases in general it is a bad idea to use RegEx to manipulate XML. With RegEx you treat XML as simple text. You will have to put knowledge about XML into your RegEx.

An XML Api can provide specific features, like Xpath support.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<JournalIssues>
  <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Print">
  </JournalIssue>
  <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Screen">
  </JournalIssue>
</JournalIssues>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//JournalIssue[@CitedMedium="Print"]') as $issueNode) {
  $issueNode->parentNode->removeChild($issueNode);
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<JournalIssues>

  <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Screen">
  </JournalIssue>
</JournalIssues>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below, but it's not recommended to use regex on XML.

```
$content = preg_replace(
    '/<JournalIssue CitedMedium="Print">(.*?)JournalIssue>/is',
    '',
    $content
);
```

Key is modifier /s

> s (PCRE_DOTALL)
>       If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are
>   excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A
>   negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character,
>   independent of the setting of this modifier.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Also (.*?) is important to don't replace other content between multiple JournalIssue blocks.